# Jquery (2) not calling AJAX Success call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-2.0

I've the following generic `PostTo` method which can be used to post data to an ASP.NET MVc Controller, without the need for repetitive mark-up, I'm  pretty sure it was working at one point, but for some reason, the `success` callback (any of it) doesn't get called.

Any thoughts? Everything looks right, and the server is responding with a valid `200 OK` response.

It is however, an empty response. I tried a different (and empty) `dataType` value, but nothing changed.

```
function PostTo(controller, action, data, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Settings.HostPath + controller + "/" + action,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (typeof (successCallback) != "undefined")
                successCallback.call(this, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check the error callback. It could still be something like a parse error. Also, the response could be empty.

Comment: can you show your action?

Comment: The action is irrelevant, and is just a method returning `void`

Comment: @Johan - the response `is` empty, but I would still like the callback to be called - any suggestions?

Comment: Adding to that - I'm getting an `Unexpected end of input` error, I assume it's trying to parse JSON that doesn't exist?

Comment: What's the mimetype set to in the controller?

Comment: The controller is a `public void method()`

Comment: It's fine - it was me, I wrote a different method (JS) that accept the `dataType` as a param, so now I just pass `text` and it works as expected..

Answer (score 3):

ajax method in your script, excepts json data from the server, but as you told in comments, your actions returns nothing (i thinks it's returns EmptyResult).

So, add any json result in your action:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return Json(new {Success = true});
}
```